# Can someone explain the recursion that this code undergoes?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

```
(define (even x)  (= (modulo x 2) 0))
(define (twice x) (* x 2))
(define (half x)  (/ x 2))  

(define (rfmult a b)
    (cond ((= 0 a) 0)
          ((= 0 b) 0)
          ((even a) (twice (rfmult (half a) b)))
          (else     (+ b (twice (rfmult (half (- a 1)) b))))))
```

I've come to the understanding that `(rfmult 3 4)` is called, the `else` statement is triggered and after that `(- 3 1)` takes place of `a` and is cut in half so then it becomes `(rfmult 1 4)`. At this point, I get lost because if it was multiplied by 2, it would never end.  I just can't seem to make sense of it in my head.

Comment: It's an algorithm based on the distributive property of multiplication. For two numbers a and b, where c is 1/2 a (2c = a) then a*b is equal to 2c*b but also 2*(c*b). And also that for any a*b where d is one less than a (d = a - 1) then a*b = a + (d * b). Note the function as written only works for integers. Just run this through a substituion model. (rfmult 3 4) turns into (+ 4 (twice (rfmult (half (- 3 1)) 4)) simply to (+ 4 (* (rfmult 1 4) 2)) and then (+ 4 (* ( + 4 (rfmult (half (- 1 1) 4)) 2)) to (+ 4 (* ( + 4 (rfmult 0 4)) 2)) to (+ 4 (* ( + 4 0)) 2))  t0 (+ 4 (* 4 2)) to (+ 8 4) to 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion ends at the 'base cases' (where there is no recursive call).  Your bases cases are `a` or `b` is `0`.

Use 'trace-define'

```
|(rfmult 3 4)
| (rfmult 1 4)
| |(rfmult 0 4)       ;; ends here
| |0
| 4
|12
```

like this:

```
(trace-define (rfmult a b)    ; <= here
    (cond ((= 0 a) 0)
          ((= 0 b) 0)
          ((even a) (twice (rfmult (half a) b)))
          (else     (+ b (twice (rfmult (half (- a 1))b))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out...... so lets call (rfmult 100 5)

1. This would then call (rfmult (100/2 5)
2. (50/2 5)*2
3. ((25-1)/2 5) *2
4. (12/2 5) * 2 + b
5. (6 5)*2
6. (3 5)*2
7. ((3-1)/2 5) *2
8. (1 5)*2 + b
9. 0!

---

Then you track upwards through the recursion.

So, in the (1 5) block the b value becomes 15 because 5*2 + 5=15

Then, the (3 15) block b becomes 15 *2 = 30

Then, (6 30) b becomes 30 * 2 = 60

Then, (12 60) 60*2 + 5 = 125

(25 125) 125 * 2 => 250

which brings us back to the first call of (50 250) where 250*2 = 500 and that is the solution of 5*100...

If this is the wrong thought process please correct me! I've been sitting on this recursive structure for about 2 hours now and am excited to see it sort of make sense!